How to find this pgf in a game of roulette?
Here's an exercise in An Intermediate Course in Probability by Gut.
The probability generating function (pgf) of a nonnegative integer-valued random variable $Y$ is $g_Y(t)=Et^Y$, and the pgf of a sum $S_N$ of a random number $N$ of i.i.d. random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ is $g_{S_N}(t)=g_N(g_X(t))$.

Exercise 6.2 Consider a game of roulette and [someone] who bets one dollar until number $13$ appears, with the roulette wheel having numbers $0,\ldots,36$. Then [they bet] one dollar the same number of times on number $36$. Find the pgf of [their] loss in the second round. Try also finding the pgf for [their] overall loss.

Here's my attempt. Let $N\in \text{Fs}(1/37)$ be the number of bets on number $13$ (here $\text{Fs}(1/37)$ is the geometric distribution that models the first success), and let $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots$ be the losses in the bets on number $36$. Thus $$Y_k=\begin{cases} 1,&\text{if number 36 does not appear}\\ -35&(\text{i.e.} -36+1)\quad\text{otherwise},\end{cases}$$and $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots$ are independent with $P(Y_k=1)=36/37$ and $P(Y_k=-35)=1/37$ (note that a negative loss is a gain).
So the player's loss in the second round equals $X=Y_1+\ldots +Y_N$. We know the generating function of $X$ is $g_X(t)=g_N(g_Y(t))$. Computing the generating function of the geometric distribution is straightforward; it is $\frac{tp}{1-(1-p)t}$ where $p=1/37$. But what is the pgf of $Y$? $Y$ seems to be both positive and negative, and hence I'm confused if it even has a pgf.
The total loss is $X+N-36$, but from the first part I am unsure how to find the pgf of this random variable.

The number of spins until the first $13$ appears follows a Geometric distribution with $p = 1/37$, i.e. the probability that the first $13$ appears on spin $n$ is $p (1-p)^n$ for $n \ge 1$. So the PGF for the number of spins is
$$g_N(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p(1-p)^n t^n= \frac{pt}{1-(1-p)t}$$
where we have applied the formula for the sum of an infinite geometric series.
If $X$ is the loss on a single spin in the second part, then $X=0$ with probability $p$ and $X=1$ with probability $1-p$ (regardless of the number of the spin). So the PGF of $X$ is
$$g_X(t) = p + (1-p)t$$
Applying the theorem quoted in the OP, the PGF of the total loss is
$$g_N(g_X (t)) = \frac{p(p + (1-p)t)}{1-(1-p)(p + (1-p)t)}$$

Thanks! I don't see how the expression for $g_N(g_X (t))$ can be true. The expected total loss is $E(X+N-36)=2$. This follows from the fact that $$EX=EN\cdot EY=37\cdot\left(1\cdot\frac{36}{37}-35\cdot\frac1{37}\right)=1,$$and $EN=37$. The left-hand derivative of a PGF at $t=1$ should give the expected value. Differentiating your expression with $p=1/37$ and evaluating at $t=1$, WolframAlpha yields $36$. Something's not right, but I don't know what.

Maybe it is supposed to be that way. Would you know how to find the PGF for his overall loss? I'm unsure which random variable describes the overall loss.

@pse The expected value of the loss is the expected value of the number of spins times the expected value of the loss on one spin: $37 \times (36/37) = 36$.  The PGF above is the PGF of the overall loss.  Frankly, I don't understand what the exercise statement means by "the loss in the second round", unless by that is meant the overall loss.   So maybe I don't understand the problem.
